# Redirect if cookie exists jquery/html

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to make a window.onload "if logged in redirect to /premium" script.

```
<script>
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
  if (!!$.cookie(Sentry_firstName)) {
    $(location).attr('/premium',url);
  }
}
</script>
```

This does not work when pasted into .HTML
any ideas? Dont need backend. can have it all in HTML.
And have i read the cookie key right? Cookie source 
 [HERE](https://www.sentrylogin.com/sentry/scripts/Sentry_AJAX_Style2014.js)

Comment: By the source of this, it doesn't look like a jQuery plugin.

Comment: source is only to show cookie keys. 
I am logged in and i dont get redirected to /premium.

Comment: Are you using [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin?

Comment: Did you forget quotes around Sentry_firstName, or is that variable declared somewhere that you're not showing?

Comment: And there is a missing parenthesis to close the `.on` method.

Comment: For starters tell us what errors are thrown in your browser console

Answer (score 2):

To test if a cookie exist you can use javascript:

`if (document.cookie.indexOf('Sentry_firstName') > -1 )` {

your code become :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (document.cookie.indexOf('Sentry_firstName') > -1 ) {
    window.location = '/premium';
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: There is a `{` missing at the end of the condition and a `)` to close the `.on()`.

Comment: Ah... And also, the `attr()` arguments are inversed... Should be `.attr( attributeName, value )`.

Comment: : $ is not defined on line 1 of script

Comment: @Balleleif: It means jQuery lib isn't loaded.

Comment: one preriquisis is to have  jquery @Louys Patrice Bessette i fix all normally

Comment: oh. thats weird, i have both of theese in my html.
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Type `$.fn.jquery` in the console and look if the jQuery version is returned. It should output `3.2.1`

Comment: $.fn.jquery
"3.2.1"

Comment: are you sure that the code is call after the jquery load ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: Wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function(){` and `});` instead of `$( window ).on( "load", function() {`

Comment: it is not. will test

Comment: @louys Your swap gave no errors, but i do not get redirected.

Comment: Does the if condition run ?

Comment: loll... I just saw it... You pretty had all possible syntax errors! change `$(location).attr(url,'/premium');` to `window.location = '/premium';`

Comment: @Jeremy How do i see that? sorry, new at this.

Comment: @ Louys : what do you think about : $(location).attr('href',"/prenium");
@ Ballelief : normally it's in your browser in chrome it's native and in firefox mozilla help

Comment: Damn. This script lets the page load before redirected. is there a way to make it redirect before page load?

Comment: @Ballelief : put the jQuery-Script tags at the end of the document.

Comment: @Balleleif: You should do this server side for a redirect before load... No client side script can execute before at least the scripts are loaded and the cookie is read...

Comment: Software based website, with flask. Can only have access to a custom.js file that i can modify, and i have no idea how to add it there to comply to the html.

Comment: where are done the include like <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/… ?

Comment: That script is on the bottom of the html Jeremy

Comment: ok... Then set the page `body` hidden in CSS: `body{ display:none;}` then add an `else` to your condition... Which would be `$("body").css({"display":"block"});` --- The page will load, but user won't see it if it has to be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the replies. This worked:

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        if (document.cookie.indexOf('COOKIEKEY') > -1 ) {
        window.location = 'URL';
            }
            }); 
</script>
```

However. Page loads and reset settings before re-entering location "URL".
Back end modification to already made .JS file and how to run it in HTML would be apreciated to.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the code that works (in your own answer), to hide the page before the decision to redirect or not is made, add this css:

```
<style>
body{
  display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

And add an `else` to your script, to display the page if no redirect.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('COOKIEKEY') > -1 ) {
      window.location = 'URL';
    }else{
      $("body").css({"display":"block"});
    }
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: The settings in main html stil overtakes. even with jquery, block and script on top of html.